# how to create an floating counter on indeces

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, pandas-loc

Maybe someone can help me here. I am quite new to Python and and I do not know how to solve my problem.

I have got a DataFrame df consisting of the columns "Value" and "A". Every time my "Value" is smaller or equal to 2 I would like to take the value of "A" but 2 indices [rows] further on and put it in the same row as "Value". Else there should be an NaN.
Here is my code but it is not writing/ creating column B:

```
def iter (df):
for i in df.index:
    if df["Value"]<=2:
        df["B"]=df["A"].loc[i+2]
    else:
        df["B"]=np.nan
```

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Sample input data e. g. in the form of output from `df.head().to_dict()` would have been helpful.

Comment: Your code not only _is not writing/ creating column B_, it raises a `ValueError`. Didn't you consider this worth mentioning?